# webform form's field not aligned

Tags: webforms

[image]

Hello,

My problem is the following :
I created a simple form using the webform module with 2 fields which are : email and message.
However the field titles are not aligned properly, and I would like to have each both field,s textarea and email input field, below each title. I've been playing with css and even the hook_form_alter() function module to fix this, but it is not working. any help will be really appreciated for this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should try `Element > edit > General > Form display > Title Display > Before`

[image]

Comment: Thanks Giorgosk for your suggestion. I had tried your solution already and I was still getting same issue however, your suggestion put on the right way to make it work. Because I tried your above  solution again "Element > edit > General > Form display > Title Display > Before", in different ways, but I also check the "field prefix" and "field sufix" fields below "Title Display", and entered <div> and </div> into them. and it is working, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Well then its probably something related to the way your theme does things ... in most themes I work with there is nothing else needed